# OrmLite where clause and SQL between with java.util.date

Tags: android, ormlite

I try to create a query with a where clause which filters between dates.  My query looks something like

```
java.util.Date date1 = ...
java.util.Date date2 = ...
where().between("datefield", date1, date2)
```

But it doesn't work.  I am building my query with the `QueryBuilder` and I use `selectRaw(...)` and `queryRaw(...)`.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, this isn't going to work because under Android, `Date` fields are being persisted as strings which don't compare right when using SQL `between`.   One way to fix this would be to store your `Date` fields as longs instead:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
private Date dateField;
```

This will store the `Date` as the epoch milliseconds long number which is comparable and which will work with `between`.

Comment: Same happen to me when interfacing with MySql, I already set dataType = DataType.DATE ... can you help me Gray?

Comment: Can you post a question to the ormlite users mailing list @BromoProgrammer?  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user

Comment: @Gray - Just a quick question: Can you think of any reason to store dates in any other format besides long with OrmLite?

Comment: Not sure @jwburnside.  With some databases, storing dates as Timestamp or strings allow you to do date manipulations such as doing searches for things in a month or a week or something.  Not 100% sure about SQLIte's date handling.